# determine pricing for ferry trips

Tags: excel, equation, formulas, price

So I am super stuck with this question and don't even know where to start from. This is the info I have:

```
Start to Finish           Number of People per Day roundtrip
Seattle to  Bainbridge    5,847 passengers         14.4 miles
Seattle to  Tacoma, WA    3,243 passengers         40.2 miles
Bainbridge to Tacoma, WA    746 passengers         42 miles
```

This whole system costs 20 million. I need to develop different prices for the roundtrip tickets in a way that will be fair and understaandable to everyone. If the costs go from 20- 22 million, the system should be felxible to adjust for that too. The hint is to use equation "y=mx+b". This is the only information that I am given. Can anyone please help me where to even start? My idea was that we should charge Tacoma,WA passengers the most money cause it's less people and longest miles, second we should charge Seatle-Tacoma,WA passengers and finally the least amount should be charged to Seattle-Bainbridge passengers because it's the least miles and most passengers. Can you guys help me formulate this in an excel and how to get a head start with this one. |

I would really aprreciate the help,
Thanks,
Nika

Comment: I believe you should bring these question to the next board meeting. I think all managers and directors at the shipping company should have their say.

Comment: Following @Andreas - this is almost definitely not going to be best answered here. It's a business question, not a technical coding question.  But, if you *do* know what formula to use, let us know and we can help.

Comment: That's how I was looking at it too. The hint that the professor gave was to start thinking about the price and not the demand. So come up with a formula that will inlcude the pricing with y=mx+b in mind where y=demand and x= price

Comment: So, you're asking us to do your homework?

Comment: @NikaDolidze What have you already tried using, how is that not working the way you wanted, and what do you need from us to help make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Consider charging all passengers a specific amount **per mile.**  The more you charge per mile, the more revenue you will generate on a daily basis.

At a minimum, the mileage rate should be set to generate enough money to cover the daily operating costs and create a maintenance reserve.

If you increase the mileage rate beyond this, you will also generate a cash stream that you can use to retire 20 million investment.  The greater the rate the quicker the payback!

Comment: Thanks for that. That's a good way to start. However is there specific function or a formula that can be used to start with?